# variable scope and closure inside a module pattern javascript instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, oop

I'm writing a jQuery plugin, and I'm writing it in a non-jquery-community-standard way, mainly 
to maintain portability and extendability.

I'm having some trouble accessing variables that were declared in the function when accessing from the prototype.

Perhaps I have this model very wrong but I hope someone can point out the correct way to achieve my goal, and that is to create Multiple instances of the same class.

My problem occurs when I try to close the window, I get a "this.auga is undefined" error.  When I create the close button (inside the build window method) I attached a click event `.click(this.hide)` - which is another method within the functions prototype.  Also my `.resize` event isn't working because the method `.centerAuga` utilizes my `this.win` property.  Getting a `this.win is undefined` error.

Why would the `.show` method have a defined `this.auga`, yet the the `.hide` method remains undefined?  I understand I'm accessing the `.show` method off the instance itself - but why dont the other methods also have access to the instance?

This is not a "Make this work please".  I'm writing this plugin to become more familiar with JavaScript.  So if anyone has any insight please - I'm all ears.

Here's a link to the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/G26aM/16/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a jQuery call back the "this" variable will point to the element that created the event even if the callback function is in your object.

To get around this at the begining of your object do:

```
var self = this;
```

And then whenever you want to refer to your object use "self" instead of "this".

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily the problem.  I think the issue is having the prototype access the active instance. I'm aware of how to assign "this" in a normal setting, I think the problem is coming from using the prototype methods with the declared instance.  What does "this" access within a the prototype?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using this in a prototype. It does look like a this reference issue conflicting with jquery. For example you do this: this.win.resize(this.centerAuga).  Which means in center Auga "this" will no longer point to your object.  But you still use it there to mean that.

Comment: I hate that you're right, cause I thought i knew what I was doing w. that. http://jsfiddle.net/G26aM/18/ <-- works